# Moving an encrypted home folder to a new drive

Tags: ecryptfs

Is there something I should be taking in to account when moving an encrypted home directory to a new drive? Is it just enough to rsync the contents away, edit fstab etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do:

- Be sure to have no user logged when doing the copy, so that encrypted directories are not mounted.
- Copy the whole `/home/`, as there is a `/home/.ecryptfs` which I think contains all the encrypted data.
- As root, run `rsync -av /home/ /other/disk/home/` in order to preserve all file attributes.

Comment: In the end I tried to remove the encryption and then just move and re-enable the encryption. Which didn't go so well so I just reinstalled Ubuntu and used a backup. One thing which I wasn't so sure was that the encryptfs makes a hidden mount (if I'm correct), wasn't sure if just moving all the files would be enough.